# How can I spell check web pages from the browser?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions, spell-check

How can I spell check web pages when browsing them? I've added the After the Deadline Chrome extension, but it only seems to work on forms and not whole web pages. I'm happy to use Firefox if that provides a solution.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are they your own pages?

Comment: Yes, they are my pages. Does it make any difference?

Comment: Yes - you should spell check the content in what ever program you are using to create the web pages.

Comment: I pull in content from a few different files to build up each web page. I'd like to do a check of the pages displayed to make sure I haven't missed anything.

Answer (score 8):

In Chrome, open the console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>. In the console, type the following and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
document.body.contentEditable = true;
document.designMode = 'on';
```

This will make the page editable and the built-in spell checker of Chrome will be able to highlight anything misspelled.

Comment: How is the console invoked?

Comment: In chrome hit  Ctrl + Shift + J for Windows OS and for Mac OS hit Cmd + Shift + J

Comment: It works for Firefox as well.

Answer (score 4):

Use the bookmarklet from [Switched.com: how-to-spell-check-any-web-site-using-firefox](https://web.archive.org/web/20120805032027/http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2009/08/10/how-to-spell-check-any-web-site-using-firefox/)

You can drag-n-drop the bookmarklet link on your bookmarks bar.
You may have to drag-select the content of your page to force refresh spell check on the website's content.

Works in Chrome.

Comment: The link is broken, it redirects to a gadget website...

Comment: Dead link, doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I have found out a way to do it.

First you need to make the content editable:

```
document.body.contentEditable = true;
document.designMode = 'on';
```

Then as you are proofreading the page, select the text you want to spellcheck, then Ctrl+X to cut and Ctrl+V to insert it back. This should trigger the spellchecking of that block of text.

Comment: Where and how should "`document.body.contentEditable = true;`" be used? It looks like JavaScript code, but is it in `about:config`?

Comment: @PeterMortensen You should type it to the javascript console of your browser.

Answer (score 1):

LanguageTool ([for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grammar-and-spell-checker/oldceeleldhonbafppcapldpdifcinji), [for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/languagetool/)) can do that. Select the text and click on the "LT" in the browser's toolbar to check static text. Text that you write yourself into forms gets checked automatically. (Disclosure: I'm the author of these add-ons).

Comment: This does work. However, it requires pinning another icon to the toolbar, selecting text (sometimes the page is long, and Ctrl+A picks up parts of the page I don't need), then clicking a toolbar button, then clicking a button within the dropdown, which copies the text and opens it, out of context, in a new tab on languagetools.com. Then, when I find problems, I have to try to find the same place on the original site. It's not useful for finding errors within the original site context, which is my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Spell Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/spell-checker/) (it hasn't been updated for newer versions of Firefox).

Comment: This plugin is insanely slow for long content.

Comment: This doesn't work in FF53

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [**SpellcheckEverything**](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/spellcheckeverything/) extension for Firefox. I’s very simple – it just forwards all the work to the spellchecker used for textareas in forms.

Inside, it works pretty much like this [well](http://lifehacker.com/5335686/use-firefoxs-spell-checker-on-any-page)-[known](http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2009/08/10/how-to-spell-check-any-web-site-using-firefox/) **bookmarklet**:

```
javascript:document.body.contentEditable='true';document.designMode='on';void%200
```

From [SpellcheckEverything @ Mozilla Addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/spellcheckeverything/), with typos fixed:

> This add-on brings the body-tag of the current webpage into the contendEditable-mode. Thus the whole page will be treated as editable content and therefore the whole text will be spellchecked.
>
> The add-on requires the Firefox-Spellcheck-Feature to be enabled. You will also need download the language files for the Firefox-Spellcheck-Feature.
>
> This only applies to version 0.2 which is available by clicking on "Versions" before it will get reviewed: A "SpellCheck" button will appear in the statusbar. A click on that button will enable SpellcheckEverything and indicate the status by changing its color to green. Turn it off by a second click on that button.

<sub>Kudos to [How can you check spelling on an existing webpage? @ Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/cs/questions/970067). Without that Q&A, I would miss this addon.</sub>

Comment: This doesn't work in FF53

Comment: This only spellchecks what you write or modify in FF. Not the entire webpage that's already written.

Comment: Seems this extension is abandonware. Last version is from 2011. I don't use it anymore, either. I found I don't need this functionality enough to search for a replacement.